# do I need to destroy a string in c++

Tags: c++, stl

if I have a string in a class, then memory is allocated. Do I have to destroy the string in the destructor? e.g.

```
class A {
  string Test;
  A() {
    Test = "hello world";
  }

  A(string &name) {
    Test = name;
  }

  ~A() {
    // do I have to destroy the string here?
  }
}
```

I'm an old c/c++ (pre stl) programmer and getting back into c++. Is the string destroyed automatically using some template magic?

tia,
Dave

Comment: in your example, does `string` resolve to `::std::string`?

Comment: The interesting thing (to me) lies in the destructor. Does C++ guarantee that the member objects are destructed after the constructor of the parent object has been called? Can I somehow prevent this to happen? (Just out of curiosity; maybe you can cite the relevant sections of the C++ standard.)

Comment: C++ guarantees that your class members will be destroyed in the opposite order from which they were constructed (which is the order in which they were declared). A more readable explanation than the C++ standard: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8183zf3x(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, std::string's resources are cleaned up automatically.  Standard strings and containers allocate/deallocate for you.  HOWEVER, a container of pointers doesn't free up what those pointers point to.  You have to loop through those yourself.

Comment: Right. That is the difference between stack and heap. +1

Comment: Thanks, (that was quick) you pre-empted my next queston about containers. Is there a way of setting the containers so that they do automatically free what they are containing? e.g. Delphi (where I'm moving from) you can set an OwnsObject flag in a list and it will automatically destroy the contained objects.

Comment: You may want to take a look at smart pointers - It's basically an object that emulates a pointer's functionality that will be deleted by itself as it leaves scope.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer

Comment: I like boost::shared_ptr myself, but I don't do much with multithreading.  Smart pointers in general, are Quite Spiffy.  Look up RAII.  Very spiffy indeed.

Comment: I've looked at smart pointers and I'll eventually use them - but it's probably to big a leap just now - baby steps :-) Thanks again to all

Comment: @elusive The `std::string` can allocate heap memory, and that too is cleaned up by in  `~std::string::string()`.  PS: I recommend avoiding the "uses namespace".  When the only namespace you're using is "std" it's not such a big deal... but when you start throwing in more it becomes a real rats' nest unless you know what class is from where.

Comment: @MarkStorer, no, pointers in strings are disposed by string destructor when they go out of scope

Comment: @datdinhquoc `std::vector<std::string>`: No problem. `std::vector<std::string*>` Leak factory, unless you iterate through the container and delete those pointers (provided they're from new in the first place... if they're pointing to a bunch of stack strings that you know won't go out of scope for the lifetime of the container, it's still not a problem). So why ever use a container of pointers?  Efficiency. It's cheaper to pass around a 64-bit pointer than it is to copy-construct "War and Peace". Easy vs efficient.  Programmer time vs system resources.  Ask a PM: programmer time IS a resource.

Comment: @MarkStorer uh yes, hm, strings inside vectors and maps

Comment: Cultural context to my previous comment:  "War and Peace" is the title of a 1400+ page book, rather than a literal string.

Answer (score 3):

No. The string's destructor will be called once an instance of A goes out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

You're not creating a pointer to the string, so Test will be allocated onto the stack (Assuming object A was allocated onto the stack). Thus, when it leaves scope, it will be deallocated automatically. If Test were a pointer it would be allocated on the heap and you would need to delete it in the destructor

Comment: We don't know that 'Test' will be on the stack.  But you're right otherwise.

Comment: True, for some reason it hadn't crossed my mind that the entire class may have been allocated onto the heap in which case Test would be on the Heap regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You clean up your mess, and the standard library cleans up its mess. The memory that a std::string allocates is its mess.

The default behaviour for a destructor is to call destructors on each base and data member. Your string is a data member, so its destructor is called. Its destructor does everything that needs to be done here, so there is no more need (and in fact it would be very wrong) to clean anything up here than if you had the string as a local variable in main().